# Laravel Passing Data From One View to Another View

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I am thinking of making a landing page from the home page, which will direct the guest to the register page. I thought of making two forms for sending data and two submit buttons in them, let's say reader and writer and according to the button they use to go to the register form page, I want to pass the `profession` string from the button in the landing page and then, place it into the register form in `/auth/register`.

```
    {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/auth/register', 'profession' => 'writer')) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Writer', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}


    {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/auth/register', 'profession' => 'reader')) !!}

    {!! Form::submit('Reader', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

It is not directing me to the page `app.com/auth/register`. But it works when I directly type the link.

What I thought was using `$profession` in `/auth/register/` and access the value and use it as a hidden field in the registeration form.

(using laravel 5.1)

---

**Edit:**

In view source:

```
    <form method="POST" action="http://app.com/auth/register" accept-charset="UTF-8" profession="writer"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="dZXQsNI1BGQ39JjDLFUEkSQzL5bTNwe8o3rpiSQL">

    <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Writer">

    </form>


    <form method="POST" action="http://app.com/auth/register" accept-charset="UTF-8" profession="reader"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="dZXQsNI1BGQ39JjDLFUEkSQzL5bTNwe8o3rpiSQL">

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Reader">

    </form>
```

---

**Edit 2:**

```
    {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/auth/register', 'profession' => 'writer')) !!}

    {!! link_to('/auth/register', 'Writer', array('class' => 'btn btn-default')) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I tried this instead. At least, now it is directing the page but I still can't access the data value of `profession`

---

**Edit 3:**

Routes:

```
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return view('pages.home');
});
```

and `https://app.com/auth/register` is working.

Comment: If you are using url, it has to be the complete url. Alternatively, you can use the route attribute. Reference: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/124/opening-a-new-html-form

Comment: @zerodin i added an edit about the view:source.. I don't think that's the problem

Comment: please send us your routes , I really don't think that the problem is sending variables from one view to another .

Comment: @TonyRaoulIscaros I added my routes as edit #3

Comment: Do I need to register a new route?

Comment: would you mind post your controller?

Comment: I didn't add a new function in controller

Comment: I've written my routes about auth/register in OP. I did not register a new controller or anything. Do I need to? I am really confused. Or do I need to add a new public function in AuthController. Or do I need to make it as view->controller->view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a step by step walkthrough on how to implement it. I tested it. So it works. This is for 'writer', but you could replicate it as you had originally planned for other professions.

I assume you've registered the Laravel Collective package since you're using the curly braces and exclamation points.

Step 1:

In your landing page view, where you have the writer button, add a hidden field with the string 'writer'. Like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['writer_path']]) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('profession', 'writer') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Writer', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Not that in the open field we are using a named route ('writer_path').

Step 2:

Register a route and a controller on your routes.php file, like this:

```
Route::post('auth/register', [
'as' => 'writer_path',
'uses' => 'SampleController@displayForm'
]);
```

Step 3:

In your sample controller, you define the displayForm method.
Within that method you first obtain the value you passed from the landing page view.

If you don't know how to create a controler, you can do

```
php artisan make:controller SampleController
```

from the command line

Because the value arrives as an array, you have to obtain the string 'writer' from the array and then pass it to the new view (the view with the registration form for the writer).

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class SampleController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function displayForm()
{
    $input = Input::get();
    $profession = $input['profession'];
    return view('writerregistration', ['profession' => $profession]);
}

}
```

Last Step:

In the new view which you will create as writerregistration.blade.php, you will display the form with the field you just passed ('profession') which contains the string 'writer'. Like this:

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

{!! Form::label('username', 'Username:') !!}
{!! Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{!! Form::label('profession', 'Profession:') !!}
{!! Form::text('profession', $profession, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{!! Form::label('email', 'Email:') !!}
{!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{!! Form::label('passowrd', 'Password:') !!}
{!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}  

{!! Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Password Confirmation:') !!}
{!! Form::password('password_confirmation', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{!! Form::submit('Sign Up', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Presto, you've populated the field in the registration form for the writer with the info on the hidden field that belonged to the writer button in the landing page.

Comment: How can I exactly do it? Can you please edit your answer? I've written my routes about auth/register in OP. I did not register a new controller or anything. Do I need to? I am really confused

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a full demonstration. Cheers

Comment: To add 'reader' you would add a different form in the landing page with another hidden field this time passing 'reader' instead of writer as the profession (similar to what you had done originally(. The displayForm method would realize you are passing reader instead of writer and that's what it would display in the registration form.

Comment: I did everything you did however I ended up not directing to anywhere. When I click on the button it doesn't do anything. When I open Network in Developer, it shows the register, however it doesn't direct me to the page. The waiting time (green one) is also long.

Comment: I still couldn't make it work. Here I put all my code and some screenshots about my problem. I would be so happy if you can help me. http://laravel.io/forum/08-05-2015-laravel-51-passing-variable-from-a-view-to-another-view

Comment: or here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821512/passing-variable-from-one-view-to-another-view-laravel-5-1/