# Passing String between views - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to create a two buttons `buyer` and `seller` in the home page, and on click of these buttons, I want the guest to get directed register page with a ~hidden input~ placed in the form depending on the value of the button pressed.

I am using Laravel 5.1

For what I am trying to achieve, do I need to register a new route and a new function?

First, do I need to use a `{!! link_to !!}` or `{!! Form submit !!}`. I thought form submit would work:

```
 {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/auth/register', 'profession' => 'seller')) !!}

 {!! Form::submit('Seller', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}

 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

My routes are:

```
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

auth/register and AuthController is the one that comes with Laravel default. I also didn't register a new public function. Is this the reason? Do I need to send the data from *view* to *controller* and then other *view* (view->controller->view). I am really confused on this one.

This is how it seems in the *view-source*:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://app.com/auth/register" accept-charset="UTF-8" profession="seller"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Cw4Het1A1M6020oQL45Cy2Q0ct46TSe6ba2g4r4C">

    <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Seller">

</form>
```

**Edit:**

I think I can't send variables between views. So do I need to register a completely new route and a controller, and two methods in it? I am really confused on this stage.

Comment: how can I do that? I'm open for alternative solutions :)

Comment: how can I insert `Session::put('key', 'value')` in form submit button?

Comment: But as there will be two different buttons, isn't it going to be a problem? What I try to do is just getting the value, I don't think the method is important. The key thing I am trying is just getting the value **without** adding it to the link like `.com/register?seller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my answer to your previous similar question for details on the implementation:

[Laravel Passing Data From One View to Another View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756318/laravel-passing-data-from-one-view-to-another-view)

To answer the questions you are posing

You can use two forms one for buyer and one for seller

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['type_path']]) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('type', 'buyer') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Buyer', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!

{!! Form::open(['route' => ['type_path']]) !!}
{!! Form::hidden('type', 'seller') !!}
{!! Form::submit('Seller', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!
```

on your landing page and then have both of this forms direct to a same named route (in this case 'type_path')

Then in your routes.php file you would reference only one controller and one method and handle the logic in that method. Again see the link to my answer to see a full implementation of this for the example of writer and reader.

Essentially as you say, you'd be sending as the hidden inputs from the view to the controller to the second view.

Answer (score 0):

You could register a new route like:

`Route::get('auth/{TYPE}/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegisterType')`

Your home page would have something like this:

```
    <a href="www.app.com/auth/seller/register">seller</a>
```

Your controller method would be something like this:

```
public function getRegisterType($type)
{
  Session::put('registerType', $type);
  return redirect('/auth/register');
}
```

Then you can access you set session variable from the controller methods `getRegister` & `postRegister`

Answer (score 0):

Have you two buttons direct to the register page with a query string parameter:

```
<a href="/auth/register?type=buyer">Buyer</a>
<a href="/auth/register?type=seller">Seller</a>
```

And then just check for the query string parameter in your **register.blade.php** view:

```
{!! Form::hidden('account_type', Request::query('type')) !!}
```

If you need to validate one of the two is present, then you could create a middleware class you apply to the login route only:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (! in_array($request->query('type'), ['buyer', 'seller'])) {
        // Error
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```