# Passing Variable From One View to Another View - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.1

After an answer to my previous question, I replicated everything the top answer said and it works perfectly for him while it doesn't for me.

I want to put two buttons on my home page (Writer & Reader) which will direct them to registration page and put the profession as a hidden field in the form.

My home page:

```
    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['writer_path']]) !!}
    {!! Form::hidden('profession', 'writer') !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Writer', array('class' => 'btn btn-warning')) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

My routes.php

```
   Route::post('auth/register', [
     'as' => 'writer_path',
     'uses' => 'ProfessionController@displayForm'
   ]);
```

ProfessionController.php

```
   class ProfessionController extends Controller
    {
      //
   public function displayForm()
   {
    $input = Input::get();
    $profession = $input['profession'];
    return view('auth/register', ['profession' => $profession]);
   }
}
```

---

When I click on the button nothing happens. When I check the Developer Tools > Network, before I click on the button, register doesn't seem however when I click it comes up but it doesn't direct me to anywhere.

When register comes there, it also shows a long bar in the timelime and `initiator = Other`. When I click on register and then, `Preview` it says `Failed to load response data`. Do you have any idea?

---

**Edit:**

- I'm using Laravel 5.1 + Laravel Collective

Source Code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://app.com/auth/register" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="qq1exVYYTrmuRBrj62HGgOxJWidUK770lF5Wv1qH">
 <input name="profession" type="hidden" value="writer">
 <input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Writer">
 </form>
```

- when I click on Chrome Developer Tools > Sources > Sources > `auth/register`, I got an error (only for one time. Other times are not showing register under `Sources`):

> TokenMismatchException in /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:

---

**Edit 2:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using [laravel collective form](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html)? Laravel 5.* no longer have the form builders that we use to have in 4.*. Also, please inspect the element of the form to make sure it is translating correctly to html.

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.1. Adding an edit to the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

Apart from what I mentioned just now in the comments
(You are registering two routes that do different things under the same path, namely

```
Route::post('auth/register', [
'as' => 'writer_path',
'uses' => 'ProfessionController@displayForm'
 ]);
```

and

```
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

)
These coexist in the same routes.php file and there might be conflicts if the urls are the same

In addition, your

```
public function displayForm()
{
    $input = Input::get();
    $profession = $input['profession'];
    return view('auth/register', ['profession' => $profession]);
}
```

is returning as a view, a route, not a named route like in the instructions:

```
public function displayForm()
{
$input = Input::get();
$profession = $input['profession'];
return view('writerregistration', ['profession' => $profession]);
```

}

This, as I said should direct you to a view that you will create in a file called writerregistration.blade.php where you should put the code in the form that I passed here at the bottom of my answer:

[Laravel Passing Data From One View to Another View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756318/laravel-passing-data-from-one-view-to-another-view/31759716?noredirect=1#comment51599193_31759716)

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks a lot for your huge help. Now, everything is working perfectly. What I have done was changing the route to `register` instead of `auth/register` and, putting an "\" before Input. It now successfully directs me to `domain.com/register` but gets the `$profession`. However, when I click on the Register button, it throws `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. Is this because Register button and methods only work in `auth/register` route and that's why it is not working in `domain.com/register`?

Comment: If you are referring to the register button in the full registration form (where it asks username, password and such) - that is, the end step of the process I described in your original question, then the reason might be that there is no action specified in the Form::open() element so laravel doesn't know what to do when you click on register. You have to tell it what route to go to or what action to take (what controller and method to use) in the Form::open() element of the registration form

Comment: I keep reading your replies to me back and forth. Thanks a lot again. Now, let's say I clicked the `writer` button and directed to `register`. Everything loaded successfully (I mean, the main registration form where normally located in `auth/register`). And this is the route I normally use to register the user `Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');`. I tried adding another route: `Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');` but still getting the same error. Where am I missing?

Comment: try reversing 'register' and 'auth/register' in your routes.php file so you have Route::post('register', [
'as' => 'writer_path',
'uses' => 'ProfessionController@displayForm'
 ]); and Route::post('auth/register'), 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister'); as your registration route. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

try by adding 'method' to Form::open

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['writer_path'], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

and use '\' on 'Input' on controller

```
$input = \Input::get();
```

Comment: same issue happening. :/ Here, I explained with some photos from Developer Tools. http://laravel.io/forum/08-05-2015-laravel-51-passing-variable-from-a-view-to-another-view

Comment: what's the output when you add following after `$profession = $input['profession'];` ?  `dd($profession); `

Comment: When I put `dd($profession);` after `$profession = $input['profession'];`, I get no output. Still nothing happens

Comment: I've tried your code on a new laravel project. It works fine. I used WelcomeController and welcome.blade instead you file names. [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ajHAkB-0-mT2pGT24wRUJRbVE/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9ajHAkB-0-mT2pGT24wRUJRbVE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why it isn't happening in my project :(? Did you change anything?

Comment: no, I only changed "\" and "method => post" Did you tried the project on the link?

Comment: I didn't run the project but I tried puttin ` \ ` and `method => post` as well on my project but no luck :(

Comment: Try again without VerifyCsrfToken middleware

Comment: How can I eliminate that? In my case, button is just refreshing the page :/

Comment: Comment `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` from app->Http->Kernel.php

Comment: I commented it out, but still it is just refreshing the page :( Console only shows `navigated to the bla.com`

Comment: I saw your code in laravel.io try commenting the two routes:
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

Comment: It might be that there is a route conflict since you are defining two post routes with the same url (the one in my example and the one you had before)