# Share form data with another view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a Laravel Application with some Angular JS, I'm using Laravel to do the routing as it's easier for my team (who rarely use JS at all) to understand later, I have a route that allows me to create briefings, this is done first by selecting some options *(which are passed as an array to the Laravel Controller and sent to the view)* and then generating the project

Now, when I have the project generated I'm taken to another view with a sidebar, this sidebar allows me to change to different **subsections** of the briefing, for instance, there's a section for Development and another for Design.

These are different routes in Laravel that take the user to different forms, the problem is that these forms need to generate conditionally with blade's `@if` command and in order to do that, I need to get the original *options* array from my generator view into all of these other views.

How can this be achieved in Laravel 5.2?

Comment: So basically you want to share some data across many views and have it available without putting it in each view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31756318/laravel-passing-data-from-one-view-to-another-view : This will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use **SESSION** ?

On submit a form, use SESSION to save some data that you need and you can easily find it at any moment with SESSION.